# Any way to make a variable into hex in python

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord.py bot right now and I want the ability to let the user encode and decode text, however from what I am looking at you can only do text that is in quotes, is there a way for me to pass in a variable?
Also this was written in a cog.
Here is my code.

```
  @commands.command()
  async def hexE(self, ctx, *, msg):
    enc = binascii.hexlify(msg)
    print(enc)
    await ctx.send(enc)
```

I also have tried many other ways but none of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you just want to convert string to hex. First you need to convert it to bytes. This can be done by using string method `.encode()`. Then you can convert it to hex by using `.hex()` method.

```
msg = "hello"
msg_hex = msg.encode().hex()
```

Output:

> '68656c6c6f'

To convert it back you can use class method `bytes.fromhex()`

```
decoded_msg = bytes.fromhex(msg_hex).decode()
```

Output:

> 'hello'